# Why is `setopt nohup` required to make `nohup watch` work in zsh?

Tags: zsh, nohup

In zsh, `setopt nohup` seems to be required to make nohup work, as follows:

```
# nohup does not work without setopt nohup
➜  /tmp  zsh
➜  /tmp  nohup watch ls &
[1] 31556
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’                                                                                                                                                   
➜  /tmp  exit
zsh: you have running jobs.
➜  /tmp  exit
zsh: warning: 1 jobs SIGHUPed
➜  /tmp  ps -fp 31556
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD

# It works well with setopt nohup
➜  /tmp  zsh
➜  /tmp  setopt nohup
➜  /tmp  nohup watch ls &
[1] 31216
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’                                                                                                                                               
➜  /tmp  exit
zsh: you have running jobs.
➜  /tmp  exit
➜  /tmp  ps -fp 31216
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
nori     31216     1  0 19:00 pts/6    00:00:00 watch ls
```

Why does zsh need `setopt nohup` since bash does not?

Comment: According to [3.18 in the FAQ](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html) you _don't_ need it: "Note that you can always run programs with nohup in front of the pipeline whether or not the option is set, which will prevent that job from being killed on logout. (nohup is actually an external command.)"

Comment: I was actually able to keep a background task executing from `zsh` without the `nohup` option (only using the `nohup` executable). [Output](https://dpaste.de/sfY5)

Comment: @Bratchley That's the correct answer: without the `nohup` option the shell sends `SIGHUP` but the `nohup` command did its job so the signal is ignored. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Well I think we may need more info from the OP so I know what I'm really answering. For instance, he doesn't really explain why he thinks it _isn't_ working. That might be good to know since it seems to be an issue with expectations.

Comment: @Bratchley I thought nohup does not work because `watch` process seems to be killed. I'll update my question.

Comment: @Bratchley you were right! that wasn't the answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nohup` is ineffective against `watch` because `watch` installs a signal handler for `SIGHUP` which overrides the one installed by `nohup`.

`nohup` works by setting the signal handler for `SIGHUP` to `SIG_IGN` which causes the signal to be ignored, and then it runs the program it was asked to run. This works well with target programs that leave the signals configured the way they were when they got started, which mainly means programs that pay no attention at all to signals. But `watch` installs a signal handler for `SIGHUP` and other signals (for the purpose of restoring the changes it makes to the terminal settings before it exits).

Comment: Wow, I never thought it does not work because of `watch`. Thanks!